# Parser for NOTAM into GIS point objects whith attributes

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geojson, parse

I am participating in a gis application development project. There is a task of planning from a drone flight application, taking into account the limitations of NOTAM. Everything would be fine if it were not for the regular NOTAM updates every hour and the need to display them.
Perhaps there is actually a ready NOTAM parser of telegrams for translating them into some GIS format, for example shp or geojson.
An example of the source file from the links:
http://www.caiga.ru/common/AirInter/series_notam/A2005281855_eng.html
http://www.caiga.ru/common/AirInter/series_notam/A2005281855_rus.html